# parametera entering approach with rosrun and roslaunch

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, my question is regarding what I noticed during my work with kinect2_bridge.

While I was launching the node via roslaunch, I was adding parameters this way:
'**roslaunch kinect2_bridge kinect2_bridge.launch publish_tf:=true**'

However this doesn't work with rosrun, which rosrun I used:
'**rosrun kinect2_bridge kinect2_bridge _publish_tf:=true**'

If I delete underscore before '**publish_tf:=true**'  the parameter will not be added.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336436/parametera-entering-approach-with-rosrun-and-roslaunch/) by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2019-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is how parameters are handled when used with rosrun. Take a look [here](https://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#rosrun).

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2019-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on 2019-10-30**:
Thanks for link and answer